# ERROR TypeError: tags.tagName.indexOf is not a function: Angular: Filter Observable<SomeObject[ ]> provided with a substring as a parameter

Tags: arrays, json, angular, string, observable

**The situation:**

I have a class with two properties, id and tagName. I have a json file with an array that matches said class. I want to extract all the items in the array that their tagName contains a given substring as a parameter, not equal to tagName but anywhere within the string. I am trying this in a service, in a function that returns an observable of type said class above. In the following attempts below I will be using `"java"` as the search parameter.

**The class:**

```
export class TechTag {
    id?: number;
    tagName!: string;
}
```

**The function inside de service that returns every object:**

```
getAllTechTags(): Observable<TechTag[]> {
    return this.http.get<TechTag[]>(this.baseUrl);
}
```

**Url of JSON file:**

```
"../assets/techTags.json"
```

**Sample of the file:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "tagName": ".net"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "tagName": "html"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "tagName": "javascript"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "tagName": "css"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "tagName": "php"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "tagName": "c"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "tagName": "c#"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "tagName": "c++"
  },
```

**How I check the results in the component:**

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

    let techTags: TechTag[];

    this.techTagsService.searchTechTags("java").subscribe(
      {
        next: (response => {
          techTags = response;
        }),
        complete: () => {
          console.log(techTags);
        }
      }
    );

  }
```

**My attempts:**

**Attempt #1**

```
  searchTechTags(tagName: string): Observable<TechTag[]> {
    return this.http.get<TechTag[]>(this.baseUrl).pipe(map(data => data.filter(tags => 
    tags.tagName == tagName)));
  }
```

**Result #1 (only returns java)**

```
[
    {
        "id": 17,
        "tagName": "java"
    }
]
```

**Attempt #2**

```
  searchTechTags(tagName: string): Observable<TechTag[]> {
    return this.http.get<TechTag[]>(this.baseUrl).pipe(map(data => data.filter(tags => 
    tagName.includes(tags.tagName))));
  }
```

**Result #2 (doesn't return javascript)**

```
[
    {
        "id": 17,
        "tagName": "java"
    },
    {
        "id": 11644,
        "tagName": "j"
    },
    {
        "id": 118435,
        "tagName": "ava"
    }
]
```

**Attempt #3**

```
  searchTechTags(tagName: string): Observable<TechTag[]> {
    return this.http.get<TechTag[]>(this.baseUrl).pipe(map(data => data.filter(tags => 
    tags.tagName.includes(tagName))));
  }
```

**Result #3 (doesn't even work)**

> ERROR TypeError: tags.tagName.includes is not a function

**Attempt #4**

```
  searchTechTags(tagName: string): Observable<TechTag[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<TechTag[]>(this.baseUrl)
      .pipe(
        map((data) => data.filter(p => p.tagName.indexOf(tagName) !== -1))
      )
  }
```

**Result #4**

> ERROR TypeError: p.tagName.indexOf is not a function

Comment: From what I see right now in attempt #3, of course, it doesn't work because tagName is not an array, it is a string, so the function includes doesn't exist there.

Comment: Indeed, as you said, tags.tagName is a string, not an array. At the time that I tried it, I didnt know .includes only worked on arrays.

Comment: The 4th attempt is right. I assume that some of array items doesn't have a tagName property. In that case just add a question mark `?` after the `tagName` prop to check if it's `undefined` and avoid the error like this `...data.filter(p => p.tagName?.indexOf(tagName) !== -1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `toString()` to tagName before filtering it, because it looks like an `object` not a `string`.

```
map((data) => data.filter(p => p.tagName.toString().indexOf(tagName) !== -1))
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked!, but tagName is already a string, or at least the property of the class is of type string, I dont know why it's not being treated as a string in this particular situation, but it works perfectly now, thank you.